# in excel, how do i treat "AB" as the same category as "BA"

Tags: excel

My data compares pairs of images: one on the left and one on the right; each image has a name (e.g., R1-1, R5-3). I would like to treat a pair that has R1-1 on the left and R5-3 on the right and a pair that has R5-3 on the left and R1-1 on the right as the same category. Is there any way to achieve this?
Currently, I created a new column called "pair", and concatenated the color names (e.g., R1-1&R5-3, R5-3&R1-1); but how do I tell excel that these two should be treated as a single categorical variable?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post some of your excel code so that we may follow what you are explaining.

Comment: Do not concatenate the name from the left with the name from the right. Instead, concatenate the min of the names (alphabetical order) with the max of the names. This returns the same result regardless which image you put on the left or on the right.

Comment: Hi, Thank you! I think this is definitely on the right track. But could you be more specific––what do you mean by taking the min of the names?